Horror movie (from the 80s/90s) where men impersonate someone’s dead mother
I watched it years ago and I only remember bits and pieces of it: 

There is this man, who lost his mother. 
Then he starts seeing her (she came back from the dead and looking quite disturbing), also stalking a woman (may be his girlfriend or something). 
Actually it's these two guys impersonating the mother (may be for trying to steal something valuable, to freak them out and get whatever they want from him). 
There is a car scene, the mother appears all of a sudden in the car and the woman freaks out and then the mother disappears into thin air. 
Another scene taking place at a mausoleum. This time two men are there, dressed up like the guy's dead mother and he thinks he is going crazy.

It was quite a cheesy yet disturbing movie (maybe disturbing at the time cause I was a kid). B movie at the best. Either from the 80s or 90s.

@unor, May I know why the tag "horror" doesn't fit the question?

@chaitanya89: Because the question is not about the horror genre (it’s about a movie that belongs to this genre; but, for example, questions about [tag:saw] shouldn’t have the [tag:horror] tag either, unless they ask about horror genre aspects of Saw). At least that’s my understanding. Related Meta discussion: The future of Genre tags

@unor You are indeed right and explained perfectly how it works. The only thing you might have completely overlooked, though, is that in their current form they can also be used for ID questions, since the meta discussion you link to seems to lack a clear consensus.

Are you sure it was a guy?

I think it was a guy but I cannot say that with 100% confidence. I have not been successful so far finding out; whomever I ask about the movie has no clue... It's frustrating...

Omg I think you are right it was a woman and I think the movie is Almost Dead. Thank you so much!
